# Typescript can't import dependencies with initialized values

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I have a file A.ts, that want's to import from file B.ts.

File B.ts looks like this:

```
export enum Test {
  A,
  B,
}
```

Version 1 of File A.ts looks like this

```
import { Test } from "@platform/ts-shared";
const testObject = {
    type: Test.A
}
```

Version 2 of File A.ts looks like this

```
import { Test } from "@platform/ts-shared";
const testObject = {} as Test
```

Version 2 is working perfectly fine. While Version 1 does not work (which is also the case for every other initialized object different from a interface or class).

I'm running my files with ts-node in an nx monorepo.

Comment: What is `"@platform/ts-shared"` doing with `B.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Version 1 of File A.ts is not working is that the Test enum is not a type, it is a value. When you import Test from B.ts, you are actually importing the values A and B, not a type that can be used to initialize an object.

If you want to use an initialized object with an imported value, you can define an interface that describes the shape of the object, and use that interface as the type of the object. For example:

File B.ts:

```
export enum Test {
  A,
  B,
}
```

File A.ts:

```
import { Test } from "@platform/ts-shared";

interface TestObject {
  type: Test;
}

const testObject: TestObject = {
  type: Test.A
}
```